# WP7 Tile Notification with invalid background image name

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

From web service, if I send a tile notification with a background image name(eg:noname.jpg) which does not exist in the app client bundle. The application tile image which is pinned to the start turns to the Phone accent color(I have set the phone theme background color as blue, so the application tile image becomes plain blue color image). Is this the expected behavior or there should not be any change in the tile image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected.

The accent colour is displayed as a layer behind any image you use on the tile. This is how you can use transparency to include the accent colour in tile image.
If you use an invalid Uri then no image will be displayed, just the background layer.